# How to add navigation controller programmatically?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

In my app there is requirement that..I have 6 buttons in a nib,
when I press any button a new nib will be loaded into the window according to the button pressed. problem is after loading the new nib If I want to come back to the previous nib (which is having all the buttons) how to add navigation controller?

what I am doing now is while loading the new nib when I pressed the button

```
objNewViewController = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objNewViewController animated:YES];
```

but by this way im not able to load the nib, it's not performing any operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil]];

[self presentModalViewController:navigationController               animated:YES];
            [navigationController release];
```

And in NewViewController:
USe this to dismiss and get back to previous view.

```
[[self navigationController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: when I do this it is loading my newViewController's nib, but the problem is it doesnt have any back button to come back.
how to solve this?

Comment: you can add leftBarButton to navigation item. Add cancel button and in its action method, dismiss the model.

Comment: `presentModalViewController` is deprecated from iOS 6.0. What can be the alternative of this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a template in Xcode for a navigation based app. It does everything you describe. Well, very close at least, only the `AnotherViewController` in `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is commented out.

Comment: thank you for the reply johan..
but the thing is the nib which is having these 5 to 6 buttons is not the first nib..
i have 2 nibs before this..after that this buttons nib will come.
here i cant take the navigation controller especially rite?
that why i wanna add the navigation controller programatically atleast to come back till the nib which contains the buttons.

Comment: In that case, create the UINavigationController using its designated initializer (-init...) and add its view when you need it. You can the push other viewcontrollers on its stack after you've created them with -initWithNib...